# Create Customer custom attribute in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I need to create customer custom attribute as datetime in magento 2.3

> Below is my code into Setup/Patch/Data/AddLastPasswordChangeCustomerAttribute.php with apply() funcation

```
public function apply()
{
    $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'last_password_change',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'last_password_change',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'backend' => '',
            'default' => null,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'group' => 'General',
        ]
    );

    $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
}
```

Also i need to display that attribute in admin side in customer account information.

I have tried but it's not display at customer account information in admin side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow below InstallData script to add customer attribute and display in customer admin form. It is working for me.

```
<?php
namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Setup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface{

const LAST_PASSWORD_CHAGNE = 'last_password_change';

/**
 * @var EavSetupFactory
 */
private $eavSetupFactory;


/**
 * @var CustomerSetupFactory
 */
protected $customerSetupFactory;

/**
 * @var AttributeSetFactory
 */
private $attributeSetFactory;

/**
 * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
 * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
    AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
) {
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
}
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        /**
         *  Customer attributes
         */
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);


        /**
         * Create customer attribute LAST_PASSWORD_CHAGNE
         */
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, self::LAST_PASSWORD_CHAGNE,
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Last Password Change',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 215,
                'position' => 215,
                'system' => false,
            ]);
        $approve_account = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, self::LAST_PASSWORD_CHAGNE)
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
            ]);
        $approve_account->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use install scripts from Magento 2.3 but Data patches. This shouldn't be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

- **You have to assign this  field at to adminhtml customer form**
- **Have to assign the  Attribute set for this attribute**

So, create a data patch and add below code.:

#### Code

```
<?php

namespace {VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchInterface;

class Abc implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create();
        $customerEntityType = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()
            ->getEntityType(\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER);
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntityType->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
        $attributeDefaultGroupId= $this->attributeSetFactory->create()->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);


        $lastPasswordChangeAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'last_password_change');

        if($lastPasswordChangeAttribute->getId()){
            $lastPasswordChangeAttribute->setData(
                'attribute_set_id',
                $customerEntityType->getDefaultAttributeSetId()
            );
            $lastPasswordChangeAttribute->setData(
                'attribute_group_id',
                $attributeDefaultGroupId
            );
            $lastPasswordChangeAttribute->setData(
                'used_in_forms', [
                    'adminhtml_customer'
                ]
            );
            $lastPasswordChangeAttribute->save();            
        }

    }
}
```

**After that, you need to Do indexing from Command line.**

Comment: Amit bera  can you send all files for this. I want to use this approach for adding custom fields in registration form.

Comment: I want to pass attribute parameters. How it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new data patch with

*

```
bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-patch Module_Vendor CreateCustomerAttribute
```

- 

Inject

```
• \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory to create the attribute
• \Magento\Eav\Model\Config to easily load the attribute
• \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute to save the attribute
```

Create data patch

```
<?php
namespace Module\Vendor\Setup\Patch\Data;


use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer as CustomerModel;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute as 
AttributeResource;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config as EavConfig;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class CreateCustomerAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
 /** @var ModuleDataSetupInterface */
 private $moduleDataSetup;
 /** @var EavSetupFactory */
 private $eavSetupFactory;
 /** @var EavConfig */
 private $eavConfig;
 /** @var AttributeResource */
 private $attributeResource;
 public function __construct(
 ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
  EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
 EavConfig $eavConfig,
 AttributeResource $attributeResource
 ) {
 $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
 $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
 $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
 $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
 }
 public function apply()
 {
 $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => 
 $this->moduleDataSetup]);
 $eavSetup->addAttribute(
 CustomerModel::ENTITY,
 'middle_name',
 [
 'type' => 'varchar',
 'label' => 'Middle name',
 'input' => 'text',
 'required' => false,
 'visible' => true,
 'user_defined' => true,
 'position' => 999,
 'system' => 0,
 ]
 );
 $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(
CustomerModel::ENTITY,
 'middle_name'
 );
 // #2 add to forms
 $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_
 customer']);
 // #3 save
 $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);
 }
 public function getAliases()
 {
 return [];
 }
 public static function getDependencies()
 {
 return [];
 }
}
```