# What is the difference between the customer attribute properties user_defined and system and what are they used for?

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, eav

How to create a customer attribute is explained in various answers such as [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/127011/70510) or [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/302089/70510). What they all have in common, is that when creating the attribute its properties `user_defined` and `system` are always defined like this:

```php
'user_defined' => true,
'system' => false,
```

For me this doesn't work. When setting the properties as seen above the attribute is not visible in the adminhtml customer edit form. When setting `user_defined => false` and `system => true` it is shown but now saved. It only works (showing in form and saving) when both properties are set to `false`.

**So my question is what is the difference between the two properties and what are they used for?**

I am aware that these properties are used to mark "system attributes" which cannot be deleted easily like describes in [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/191535/70510). I am looking for a more in depth answer what the difference between `user_defined` and `system` is. In addition what are both properties used for individually?

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191523/whats-the-difference-between-an-user-defined-attribute-and-non-user-defined-att . In this link it explain good one

Comment: Unfortunately this answer only says that `user_defined` marks attributes as "system attributes" I am aware that both properties are marking attributes as "system attributes". I am looking for an answer that describes the differences between them both and a more in depth approach in what they are used for. Like: "It is used in X places to determine X"

Comment: Magento system attributes are set to false for user_defined so our custom attributes should be set to true. System attributes can not be deleted so if you set false to user_defined, your attribute will work as system attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user_defined` property [has already been explained](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191523/whats-the-difference-between-an-user-defined-attribute-and-non-user-defined-att), so let's have a look at `system`.

First, note that `system` is only used for customer and customer address attributes, while `user_defined` is a core property of all EAV attributes. They map to the following database tables and columns:

- `user_defined` => `eav_attribute.is_user_defined`
- `system` => `customer_eav_attribute.is_system`

I never paid much attention to `system` because it seems redundant, but looking at the code, it is only ever used in two occasions:

- customer system attributes (except `password_hash`) are not imported with the customer import, if they are also set to not visible, see `\Magento\CustomerImportExport\Model\Import\Customer`
- customer address system atttributes are not imported with the customer import, if they are also set to not visible, see `\Magento\CustomerImportExport\Model\Import\Address`

I can only guess why they don't use `user_defined` for the same purpose.

It is also interesting that the filter methods are implemented in the generic `Magento_Eav` model (see `\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\Collection::addSystemHiddenFilter()` and `\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\Collection::addSystemHiddenFilterWithPasswordHash`) although it obviously only is applicable to the customer attributes.

Answer (score 0):

system > you cannot delete it this attribute from admin and it is created by magento core
user_defined : you can delete it and generally when u create custom attribute it will be user_defined.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer my question.